# Interfacing Ada with an asynchronous interface in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, asynchronous, boost-asio, ada

I have this task of designing a new interface for a distributed application (multiple processes running on a single computer, not physically distributed - yet) which is comprised of many graphical panel modules written in C++/OpenGL and a single module written in Ada.

The modules share information on the form of parameters (pieces of scalar non-structured information e.g.: ints, strings, floats, etc...). I intend to design an asynchronous socket based component (which I'll call hereafter 'Interface Component' or IC) to be linked by each module based on Boost::Asio library with two simple 'client' primitives:

```
Put([ParameterName], [DestinationModule], [Payload], [Type])
Get([ParameterName], [Sourcemodule], [Payload])
```

**ParameterName**: Designates a unique parameter name
**DestinationModule/SourceModule**: Addresses a module in the system
**Payload**: Actual data
**Type**: string or value that identifies the type of the passed parameter

Each of these primitives are treated on the server-side by two corresponding functions (on the IC):

```
//No function parameters shown here as I don't know
//exactly how I'm going to do this
ProcessPutRequest()
ProcessGetRequest()
```

Because the processing of incoming commands will be started by the IC, I intend to use function handlers which will be passed to the functions above. This way each programmer responsible by each module can process incoming commands and perform the necessary type conversions on his own code.

The question is... is this possible in Ada? I know one can import functions in C++ and call it from Ada programs btu is it possible to pass function handlers from Ada to a C++ component?

(a side-question is: do you have any suggestion of a better way of implementing this interface?)

Comment: Do you mean anything by "function handler" aside from what you'd be able to do in plain C by passing in the address of the handler function? You can certainly write the equivalent of such a handler function in Ada. Though if the Ada calls your Get() I don't see why you'd want to?

Comment: Oops, I think I should have been more complete on my question:

I want use this interface to enable each module of my application to perform both client and server operations.

As a server, the module will need to process incoming data. When this data (parameters or messages) arrives, it is processed by the Interface Component. 

The question is: how do I get the module to process the incoming data without polling the IC? The idea of using handlers was to call them so the module code can be called whenever a message arrives on the IC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the semantics of `Get()` are. Does it wait for new data? return the last data received? (in which case, what happens if no data has been received yet?)

Assuming a callback scheme and Ada 2005, you might for a start consider a spec like

```
generic
   type T is private;
package Interfacing is
   --  'put' not shown
   type Receiver is not null access procedure (Value : T);
   pragma Convention (C, Receiver);
   procedure Register
     (Parameter_Name : String;
      From_Module : String;
      To_Be_Received_By : Receiver);
end Interfacing;
```

I'm assuming that the IC will organise marshalling and the list of registered callbacks.

One point to be wary of: in this scheme, the Receiver procedure is called in the context of a foreign (non-Ada) thread which may cause problems with the Ada runtime's tasking support. Assuming you're using GNAT, you should look at `GNAT.Threads` (file `g-thread.ads` in the runtime). You need to get the thread registered as soon as possible, for example before doing any `String` operations such as catenation.

Answer (score 5):

Coding up socket-based communications is straightforward in both languages, especially so for an interface that needs to pass only scalar values.

Creating separate language-appropriate components for the modules will be *far* easier and quicker than trying to get this kind of mixed-language interfacing and linking working. Don't get me wrong, that can be done, but I would require a compelling reason to get me to go that way, versus coding up separate, simple socket data processing interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend building an interface that tries to combine languages using essentially an RPC interface with callbacks. That will be very complicated and may interact badly with Ada's task mechanism.

Instead, design a method of passing *messages* from one component to another. You could do this through sockets, for example. A message can be any reasonably sized blob of data at that level. Then, on top of that facility, implement code in each of C++ and Ada that can pack and unpack useful messages in a manner that's appropriate for each language.

Once you've got a robust message-passing interface, you can build anything you like on top of that. But the key is, you won't need to build anything that calls "into" the other language.

Comment: Hmm, you're saying that having a unified component isn't worthy the trouble of interfacing the C++ and Ada code? Note that the IC I'm talking about is intended to be linked to the Ada code and not called through RPC.

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood when you said "multiple processes running on a single computer".

Answer (score 3):

Regarding linking Ada with c++ code, there is a switch in the gcc that creates ada headers from .h & .cpp & .c files : [-fdump-ada-spec](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) and there is a howto with caveats [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Generating-Ada-Bindings-for-C-and-C_002b_002b-headers.html#Generating-Ada-Bindings-for-C-and-C_002b_002b-headers).

My caveat: I have not used it, just know of it.

Comment: Another (admittedly rather obvious) caveat is that both the C++ and Ada side have to be compiled with gcc.

Answer (score 1):

In general, C++ does not play well with other languages. You will probably have to tell both sides to use the `C` calling convention, which is typically not available for non-static member functions.

So whatever nifty class gynmastics you want to do with Boost will probably have to be dumbed down to a simple C-ish interface to talk to the outside world (in this case, your Ada code).

There is sort of a "pattern" available for doing stuff like this. It probably even has a name, but I'm not a pattern guy so I don't know it. What you do is provide a static member function that takes a pointer to the class as a parameter, and internally calls itself through that class pointer. Then you make that static member function (and the `this` pointer you want to use for it) available for the external (non-C++) code to call. I use this all the time to give OS "callback" routines C++-like interfaces.

```
class callback {
    void register () {
       // Register the callback. This usually involves somehow pointing the 
       // other side to our static do_it() routine and passing it our 
       // current "this" pointer.
    };

    void do_it(); // The member function we want callable from outside C++

    static extern "C" void do_it (callback * instance) {
        instance->do_it();
    }
};
```